# How would you describe the connectivity of coordinates?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction

I'm trying to get a Human pose from their body joints. 
The number of body joints coordinates is 14 for one person (ex. ankle, knee, hip etc)

And I need to give their connectivity between the coordinates (ex. ankle-knee, knee-hip) as an input of DNN model.

I used to use the relative coordinates (ex.x1-x2, y1-y2) for giving the direction between joints, but there were limitations to increase predict performance.

I want to get a fresh and creative idea you have.
If you have any ideas, let's share.

Thanks

Comment: Since this does not directly have anything to do with the tags you provided, I would request you to edit this maybe into `machine-learning` or `feature-extraction`.

Comment: Please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that SO is *not* a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1):

A commonly used convention for selecting frames of reference in robotics applications is the Denavit and Hartenberg (D–H) convention which was introduced by Jacques Denavit and Richard S. Hartenberg. In this convention, coordinate frames are attached to the joints between two links such that one transformation is associated with the joint, [Z], and the second is associated with the link [X].

The coordinate transformations along a serial robot consisting of n links form the kinematics equations of the robot.

You can check out the wiki link for the same here: [DH-Parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denavit%E2%80%93Hartenberg_parameters)

Now to implement this in Python there are lot's of open-source module is available. One such is [uw-biorobotics/IKBT](https://github.com/uw-biorobotics/IKBT), or if you can refer to [Python_robotics](https://github.com/prfraanje/python-robotics)